# View is showing but printing width shows 0

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I'm creating my view programmatically with this code :

```
      let statusfilterui = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 300, 0, 0))
    var height : CGFloat = 0
    var width : CGFloat = 0
    self.cancelledByAdmin.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
    if width == 0{
        width = self.cancelledByAdmin.frame.width
        height = self.cancelledByAdmin.frame.height
    }
    let cancelledByAdminlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
    cancelledByAdminlabel.text = "لغو شده توسط پذیرش"
    cancelledByAdminlabel.sizeToFit()
    self.cancelledByAdmin.frame = CGRectMake(cancelledByAdminlabel.frame.width+10, 0, 0, 0)
    let cancelledLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, height+10, 0, 0))
    cancelledLabel.text = "لغو شده توسط کاربر"
    cancelledLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.cancelled.frame = CGRectMake(cancelledLabel.frame.width+10, height + 10, 0, 0)
    let reservedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 2*(height + 10), 0, 0))
    reservedLabel.text = "لغو شده توسط پذیرش"
    reservedLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.reserved.frame = CGRectMake(reservedLabel.frame.width+10, 2*(height + 10), 0, 0)
    let deprecatedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 3*(height + 10), 0, 0))
    deprecatedLabel.text = "منقضی شده"
    deprecatedLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.deprecated.frame = CGRectMake(deprecatedLabel.frame.width+10, 3*(height + 10), 0, 0)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(self.cancelledByAdmin)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(cancelledByAdminlabel)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(self.cancelled)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(cancelledLabel)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(self.reserved)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(reservedLabel)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(self.deprecated)
    statusfilterui.addSubview(deprecatedLabel)
    print(statusfilterui.frame.width)
    statusfilterui.sizeToFit()
    print(statusfilterui.frame.width)
    self.filterview.addSubview(statusfilterui)
    print(statusfilterui.frame.width)
```

And I want center my statusfilterui by getting width of view but the problem is I'm printing `statusfilterui.frame.width` 3 times and every time its printing 0.0 in console. what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `statusfilterui` to parent first. Then call `statusfilterui.sizeToFit()`. It should then work.

```
parentView.addSubview(statusfilterui)
statusfilterui.sizeToFit()
```

[Apple doc on sizeToFit()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit)